# Reading Strings into an array, column wise

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to read String objects into a 2d array, from a `char` array, using column-major ordering:

This is what I've tried:

```
int x = 0;
for (int column = 0; column < matrix[0].length; column++) {//cols
     for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++, x++) {//rows
         if(matrix[row][column] == null) {
             if (x < ciphertextCharacters.length) {
                 matrix[row][column] = Character.toString(inputChars[x]);
             }
         }
    }
}
```

given an input array (inputChars = ['t', 't', 'g', 'e', 'i', 's', 'n']) the resulting 2D array should be:

```
+---+----+----+
| t | e  |  s |
+---+----+----+
| t | i  |  n |
+---+----+----+
| g | *  |  * |
+---+----+----+
```

Note that before this code runs, the "*" strings are already in the array - and that's why I'm only adding new values when the index is null.

Currently, the resulting 2D array I'm getting is:

```
+---+----+----+
| t | e  |  n |
+---+----+----+
| t | i  |null|
+---+----+----+
| g | *  |  * |
+---+----+----+
```

Which is not what I need.

Comment: you increment your `x` too often. move `x++` from the loop declaration to the end of the `if` block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you place `inputChars[x]` into `matrix[row][column]` based on the outcome of a condition, but `x` is incremented unconditionally:

```
for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++, x++) {
//                                            ^^^
```

Replacing unconditional increment in the loop with a conditional increment on assignment should fix this problem:

```
for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
    ...
    matrix[row][column] = Character.toString(inputChars[x++]);
    ...
}
```